# MVVM Light Toolkit - RelayCommands, DelegateCommands, and ObservableObjects

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light, mvvm-foundation

I just started experimenting with Laurent Bugnion's [MVVM Light Toolkit](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/). I think I'm going to really like it, but I have a couple questions.

Before I get to them, let me explain where I'm coming from. I currently use a combination of Josh Smith's [MVVM Foundation](http://mvvmfoundation.codeplex.com/) and another project on Codeplex called [MVVM Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/14962). I use `ObservableObject` and `Messenger` from MVVM Foundation and `DelegateCommand` and `CommandReference` from MVVM Toolkit.

The only real overlap between MVVM Foundation and MVVM Tookit is that they both have an implementation for `ICommand`: MVVM Foundation has `RelayCommand` and MVVM Tookit has `DelegateCommand`. Of these two, `DelegateCommand` appears to be more sophisticated. It employs a `CommandManagerHelper` that uses weak references to avoid memory leaks.

With that said, here are my questions:

1. Why does MVVM Light use `RelayCommand` rather than `DelegateCommand`? Is the use of weak references in an `ICommand` unnecessary or not recommended for some reason?
2. Why is there no `ObservableObject` in MVVM Light? `ObservableObject` is basically just the part of `ViewModelBase` that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, but it's very convenient to have as a separate class because view-models are not the only objects that need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. For example, let's say you have a DataGrid that binds to a list of `Person` objects. If any of the properties in `Person` can change while the user is viewing the DataGrid, `Person` would need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. (I realize that if `Person` is auto-generated using something like LinqToSql, it will probably already implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, but there are cases where I need to make view-specific versions of entity model objects, say, because I need to include a command to support a button column in a DataGrid.)

Thanks.

P.S. Here is the code for `DelegateCommand` from the MVVM Toolkit:

https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1ApCx5SbCfHi5fBhv8Ki3zA6j34sp2t80LQZdj89v8cU

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the issue raised by the first question has been solved in the latest build:

According to [The MVVM Light Toolkit Codeplex site](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) (under "Raising the CanExecuteChanged event manually"), the `CommandManager` has been eliminated altogether.

As for `Observable Object`, I have added [an item to the Issue Tracker](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/workitem/7516) on the Codeplex Site.

Comment: `ObservableObject` has been implemented as well now.

Answer (score 1):

You can also consider [Catel](http://catel.codeplex.com). It supports a DataObject (both generic and non-generic) that support exactly what you are looking for (an object implementing INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo, and much more). Then, the ViewModelBase is derived from the very powerful DataObjectBase class, so you can use the DataObjectBase for data objects, and the ViewModelBase for view models.

It also saves you from creating messengers since you can simply use the InterestedIn attribute on a view model to receive change notifications of another view model.

Answer (score 0):

Both of your questions strongly suggest to me that you prefer to use something *more* than the View Model concept to define business logic.

The `DelegateCommand` defines a *separate* class apart from the View Model. The `ObservableObject` is an instance of a *separate* class apart from the View Model. This is not a rule but personal preference of the moment: the View Model is sufficient for me as a container for business logic, relating to visuals. This may betray my preference for MVVM Light---which I do not find lacking at the moment.

I'm not quite certain about what's going on in the DataGrid example. What I can say is that the DataGrid is not very flexible---however, in WPF, the `DataGridTemplateColumn` can declaratively bind a View Model to a View (e.g. a User Control). So perhaps this makes sense:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataView="{x:Type m:YourViewModelForButton}">
        <v:YourViewWithButton/>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Comment: `RelayCommand` is also a separate class. So is `ViewModelBase`. As for my DataGrid example, it might just be a matter of terminology. I think of *view-models* in MVVM as something you bind to Views through the DataContext. But I also think that you can have view-models for domain objects (i.e., entities). For example, `Person` might have an `DateOfBirth` property. `PersonViewModel` might have additional properties, like `Age`, `IsSelected` (for use with a DataGrid check-box column), and `ToggleSelectionCommand` (for use with a DataGrid button column).

Comment: @DanM Usually my domain objects are part of the viewmodel. For instance in your case I would have an icollection<person>, selectedPerson property, then I would have the properties of the person as seperate properties bound to the selectedPerson.